# Headphones not detected as Docking Station analog output in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa, docking

I have a **Lenovo T490s** that I plug into a **Lenovo ThinkpadUltraDockingStation**. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to **20.04**. The problem is that now when I plug in the headphones in the docking station nothing happens, i.e. the sound continues to come from the laptop built-in audio.
Please note the following:

- this happens also if in Settings > Output Device I set Analog Output - ThinkPad Dock USB Audio;
- with the same laptop running Windows the headphones output in the docking station works fine, which makes me think that it is a bug in Ubuntu itself.

So far I've tried multiple solutions found around the web, which involve for instance editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, but nothing worked. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot.